# Autocomplete autofill many citys' name in the same textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Currently I am using this plugin (example at the end of page)

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

If I type "p", then "php" come out.

How can I modify the plug-in so that if I type SPACE or "," and then type "c", then c++ will come out? Therefore, what I can have in the textbox is "php, c++"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you need "SPACE" or "," when jquery autocomplete multiple does evrything for you.. check this out

```
.autocomplete({
 ......
 select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
 });
```

you can have a look to jquery autocomplete multiple example.. [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) is the link

> This is an example showing how to use the source-option along with some events to enable autocompleting multiple values into a single field.

you can click view source link in the example and check it out how they have done..

Comment: cheers..happy coding.. :)... let me know if any problem exist...